# spark broadcast join error even though spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1

Tags: apache-spark, join, broadcast

I a static dataframe of size about 5GB(staticDF as shown below) and a spark streaming data. I need to perform a left join on them as shown below:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)
println("autoBroadcastJoinThreshold = " + spark.conf.get("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold")) // displays -1
val result = streamingData.join(staticDF, ($"key1" == $"key2"), "left")
```

I need to do a left join as I need all rows from streaming data and only matching values from staticDF. But the above join statement causes this error:

```
ERROR Could not execute broadcast in 300 secs.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.doExecuteBroadcast(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:167)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeBroadcast(SparkPlan.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastNestedLoopJoinExec.doExecute(BroadcastNestedLoopJoinExec.scala:357)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:393)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.EventTimeWatermarkExec.inputRDDs(EventTimeWatermarkExec.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:629)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:128)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.doExecute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingDeduplicateExec.doExecute(statefulOperators.scala:442)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.AppendColumnsExec.doExecute(objects.scala:273)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:128)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.doExecute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec.doExecute(SortExec.scala:107)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FlatMapGroupsWithStateExec.doExecute(FlatMapGroupsWithStateExec.scala:107)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec.doExecute(objects.scala:197)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.doExecute(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:254)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapPartitionsExec.doExecute(objects.scala:197)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:393)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.MapElementsExec.inputRDDs(objects.scala:219)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SerializeFromObjectExec.inputRDDs(objects.scala:115)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.inputRDDs(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:629)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:183)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:134)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsWriter$.write(EventHubsWriter.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSink.addBatch(EventHubsSink.scala:39)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$5$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:568)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:228)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:158)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$5.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:566)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:251)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:565)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:207)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:175)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:175)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:251)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:175)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:169)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:296)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:208)
```

Why does it try to do a broadcast join here even though I have specified it as -1? Can someone help me find a way for this?

If I increase broadcast timeout then I get another error as:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.OutOfMemorySparkException: Size of broadcasted table far exceeds estimates and exceeds limit of spark.driver.maxResultSize=4294967296. You can disable broadcasts for this query using set spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1
```

But I have already disabled broadcast!

Any help or suggestion is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this info helps.. but staticDF is `persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)` while streamingData is not cached/persisted.

Comment: Do you have adaptive property enabled in Spark ? Can you check the environment tab in spark UI of  spark job ?

Comment: @user3868051which spark version?

Comment: I am using spark 2.3

Comment: @Constantine how does the adaptive property help? I have not set it by myself and I cannot see any such config in Spark UI env tab.

Answer (score 1):

When facing a similar issue (using Spark 3.1), the following Spark settings prevented the join from using a broadcast:

spark.sql.adaptive.enabled=false
spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1

As documented here (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#adaptive-query-execution), Spark's Adaptive Query Execution will in some situations automatically switch the join type to broadcast, even if a broadcast join was not specified via the join threshold. By default, spark.sql.adaptive.enables is true (and for good reason, since it will generally improve query performance). However, when strange things are happening, disabling it is a good try.